# MySQL error 1054

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to make my MySQL table insert stuff through MySQLi but it throws error 1054 Unknown Column saying that one of my values is my column, I dont know what causes this error. here is my code:

```
$mysqli -> query('INSERT INTO `cities` (`Code`, `Name`, `lattitue`, `longitute`) VALUES ( `' . $_GET['code'] . '` , `' . $_GET['name'] . '` , `' . $_GET['lat'] . '` , `' . $_GET['long'] . '` )')
```

here is the output:

> INSERT INTO `cities` (`Code`, `Name`, `lattitue`,
>   `longitute`) VALUES ( `kllk` , `kl` , `9458` , `6568` )failed: (1054)
>   Unknown column 'kllk' in 'field list'

Thanks, help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL insert statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7537500/285587)

Comment: @YourCommonSense you're smoking stuff that's bad for you? a) I answer the question on how to fix the error, b) I then point towards documentation on parametrized queries as a better fundamental solution for the issue, to avoid c) the possibility of SQL injection which I link an explanation for, and d) I do it without, like you, linking to an explanation on how to fix this with a **deprecated** API. You're misinforming users on purpose, calling a fundamentally correct answer wrong, and linking to an outdated answer as 'better' without explanation - now that's just plain dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use real apostrophes (`'`) around string constant values, not backticks (`` ` ``) - those are used for escaping reserved words in queries. MySQL is now thinking you want to get the value for `Code` from a field named `kllk` instead of the string `kllk` as you seem to want.

To the point, replace:

```
VALUES ( `' . $_GET['code'] . '`
```

with:

```
VALUES ( \'' . $_GET['code'] . '\'
```

And repeat this for the other values. After that make sure you go read up on [parametrized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), concatenating the values in there isn't good practice and could open up some [*nasty* security exploits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).